# If f(n) is Θ(h(n)) and g(n) = O(h(n)) then f(n) + g(n) is Θ(h(n)). True or False

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

I have been trying to prove/disprove the above, 
I have proved that if f(n) is Θ(h(n)) and g(n) = O(h(n)) then f(n) + g(n) is O(h(n))
but now when I am trying to prove/disprove f(n) + g(n) is also Ω(h(n) I am facing a problem. Below is my approach.

From given,

There exists b,c > 0 such that b.h(n) =< f(n) <= c(h(n)) and exists a > 0 such that g(n) <= a.h(n)

I proved O(h(n)) by adding the above two inequalities, but to prove/disprove lower bound formally I am stuck since I do not have a lower bound to g(n) but have a lower bound only to f(n).

Also I am getting confused if the big-oh notation consist of strict inequalities always or not eq. if f(n) is Θ(h(n)) does the following statement hold :

There exists b,c > 0 such that b.h(n) =< f(n) =< c(h(n)).

Thank you.

Comment: Strict or non strict doesn't matter, you can modify the constants.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `f` and `g` positive,

```
f + g >= f, g
```

implies

```
f + g = Ω(h(n)).
```